# Polygons disappearing from display in QField

Tags: polygon, qfield

Being an extreme novice, I've set up a simple test/tutorial project with QGIS 3.22.4-Białowieża and QField 2.0.14 (on a LG G6 running Android 9), with one Geopackage layer for points and another for polygons; the points behave as expected, appearing on the display after being created, but the polygons disappear after creation, regardless of whether their layer has the 'show on map' checkbox ticked or not.  Indeed, their behavior is pretty much the same as that of the points when 'show on map' is not ticked, in that they do appear (in yellow) when the 'show features' menu item is activated, and disappear when it is closed.

Comment: No, it was set by QGis to a default which I would assume to be sensible, but unchecking it makes no difference to the behavior. Same when I unchecked all of the other rendering options (also tried with raster checked).

Comment: I've yet to work out a bug at work where we have several projects that seemingly randomly have the opacity set to 0 for new layers added. Just to be sure, have you checked the opacity for the layer and whether 'Enable symbol layer' has been checked (I have once accidentally unchecked it) ?