# Visualization of polygons created on Qfield on QGIS computer

Tags: qfield

I didn't arrive to find the polygones creates on a project on Qfield and well synchronize on Qfield cloud with my computer on QGIS. How it's done ?
I create polygones with editor mode on some layer but after synchronisation I continue to see them well in Qfield but not in QGIS.
It is said : WARNING    délimitationferme   Non ASCII character detected in the layer filename.Working with file paths that are not in ASCII might cause problems.It is highly recommended to rename them to ASCII encoded paths.

Comment: I think I had a similar problem, described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429066/polygons-disappearing-from-display-in-qfield My problem occurred with a Geopackage layer but not with a shapefile one. So I judged it to be a bug and filed a bug report, yesterday. We'll see what happens ... Link to my bug report: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/2800 We'll see what happens, if it is real or if I get knocked down as a hopeless n00b.